# Are there any resources for teaching OpenGL to a Direct3D programmer?

Tags: opengl, directx

I have a good grasp of Direct3D 9, and now I want to learn some OpenGL. I have the OpenGL Redbook, sixth edition, and it has a lot of good information, but it also has a lot I already know from my D3D work. I'd like a rundown of all the differences and equivalences in OpenGL and Direct3D. Does anyone know where I might find such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both one and the same, if you're looking for feature differences then check wikipedia.
First the big one:
DirectX has a wider scope than OpenGL in that DirectX is composed of DirectSound, DirectPlay and Direct3D etc. Whereas Open Graphics Library is just about graphics.

From my perspective of working with them, DirectX is much better designed and uniform across platforms, whereas OpenGL is just a spec and is interpreted differently across different implementations WIDELY (ATI and Nvidia just bitch at each other constantly throughout development). this makes OpenGL a bit harder to handle, there are no nice and easy features since 3.1

What OpenGL gives is an ability to hack and exploit to your hearts content, it transcends directX with supreme flexibility. You feel alot closer to the hardware in OpenGL and you get a better idea of what's going on. I always found directx to be a bit of a handicap, if you wanted to make a professional game then go with directX, but OpenGL is more free-wheeling/fun than DX; you will definitely learn more and the lack of perfect additional layers around makes you work that bit harder.

To get started read the blue/orange and yellow book. also try GXBase instead of Glut..